# TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got '_Element'

Tags: python, lxml

have this Python script that is producing an error for some reason. The error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper2.py", line 79, in <module>
    etree.SubElement(coinx, "trader", {'variable': coinx}).text = prices[coin]["trader"]
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3136, in lxml.etree.SubElement
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 199, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 194, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 323, in lxml.etree._initNodeAttributes
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 334, in lxml.etree._addAttributeToNode
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1538, in lxml.etree._utf8
TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got '_Element'
```

The script causing this is:

```
root = etree.Element("root")

for coin in prices:
    coinx=etree.Element("coin")
    etree.SubElement(coinx, "trader", {'variable': coinx}).text = prices[coin]["trader"]
    etree.SubElement(coinx, "metal").text = prices[coin]["metal"]
    etree.SubElement(coinx, "type").text = prices[coin]["type"]
    etree.SubElement(coinx, "price").text = prices[coin]["price"] # Needs scraper code to function correctly
    root.append(coinx)

fName = 'data.xml'
with open(fName, 'wb') as f:
    # remove encoding here, in case you want escaped ASCII characters: &#163;
    f.write(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True))
```

Script is designed to output information to an XML file (data.xml).

New to using the LXML python module and cannot seem to find out how to solve it. If someone could help me out then that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Try `{'variable': coin}`

Comment: Tried it, now its throwing this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper2.py", line 82, in <module>
    etree.SubElement(coinx, "price").text = prices[coin]["price"] # Needs scraper code to function correctly
KeyError: 'price'`

Comment: If you have a KeyError then I suggest you check your `prices` dictionary.

Comment: Working demo with a copy--paste of your code with the `{'variable': coin}` fix at https://repl.it/repls/StylishHomelyArea#main.py

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is in the initial part of your stacktrace:

```
etree.SubElement(coinx, "trader", {'variable': coinx}).text = prices[coin]["trader"]
```

You create a new element named *trader*, as a child of *coinx*.
The actual reason of failure is in *{'variable': coinx}*.

The third parameter of *SubElement* is *attrib* - a dictionary of attributes.
In this case you attempt to create a single attribute named *variable*, for now OK.
The problem is that the **value** of this attribute should be a **string**,
passed as either *bytes* or *unicode*.

But the value which you passed is *coinx* i.e. the parent **element**.

Probably you should pass some other content here.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass some other content"?

Comment: I wrote "some other content" because you can not pass an *Element* in the place where a **text** is required. Maybe it should be a **text content** of some element.